# Identifier Expected while declaring key value array in IE - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this code:

```
var arr = "val=value1&val2=value2"; //coming from query string
 var [key, val] = arr.split('=');
 return "." + swapped[key.toLowerCase()][val.toLowerCase()];
```

however, I am having this error on the second line:

> Expected identifier

I am having this issue on IE, it's working fine on chrome/firefox.

Any ideas?

I am doing maintenance for an existing site and they're having this issue on IE.

Edit

Here's the full code I have:

```
 url = decodeURI(url);
    var swapped = Object.keys(settings).reduce(function (obj, key) {
        obj[key.toLowerCase()] = Object.keys(settings[key]).reduce(function (obj2, key2) {
            obj2[settings[key][key2].toLowerCase()] = key2;
            return obj2;
        }, {});
        return obj;
    }, {});
    return url.toLowerCase().split(/[?&#]/).slice(1).map(function (arg) {
        var [key, val] = arg.split('=');
        return "." + swapped[key.toLowerCase()][val.toLowerCase()];
    });
```

Comment: IE doesn't support destructuring syntax.

Comment: What other syntax can I replace it with? I am not that familiar with JavaScript

Comment: `var key = arr.split('=')[0];
 var value = arr.split('=')[1];`

Comment: with [key, value], you assign value at 0 index to key and 1st index to value, assign them separately and it will work in ie too.

Comment: thanks @A.J, so the next line would like? how do I write it all together?

Comment: You could paste your ES6 code into http://babeljs.io and see what ES5 code it generates. By the way, it doesn't make sense to split that input string on `=`, because it contains more than one key/value pair.

Comment: @Jacky : I have another point are you sure about your logic because this way you get 'val' in in key and `value1&val2` in val.

Comment: @A.J, please have a look at my updated question. This code is for swapping the keys of an object in place of values based on url provided. it works fine in chrome, I don't really understand it, but I have to do maintenance for it.

Comment: @nnnnnn, I am not familiar with ES6, I am a bit familiar with just JavaScript. Here's my updated code if you have an idea

Answer (score 1):

The code was written in ES6 as stated in comments, so I converted the code to ES5 using transpiler, and it worked.